# LDAP :Failed to find add in mandatory or optional attribute list

Tags: ldap

I am trying to import an ldif file which has following content-

```
DN: cn=myUser,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetorgperson
objectclass: orcluser
objectclass: orcluserV2
cn: myUser
givenname: myUser
mail: myUser
orclsamaccountname: myUser
sn: myUser
uid: myUser
userpassword:: somepassword


dn: cn=Administrator,cn=Groups,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com
objectclass: person
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=myUser,cn=Users,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com
```

When I do this, LDAP throws follwing error

```
javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Failed to find add in mandatory or optional attribute list.];
 remaining name 'cn=Administrator,cn=Groups,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com'
```

The user gets imported, but it is not added to the group(Group exists). What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

`uniqueMember` is not allowed or required by the `person` objectClass. Use the `groupOfUniqueNames` objectClass.